# React: Function inside my form's onSubmit handler not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jsx

Forgive me, as I am only 2 days into learning React.

I have a SearchForm component, which is a simple form where a number can be submitted. I would like the onSubmit handler inside this form to display another component, called SearchResult, which for now only displays the number that we just looked up. For some reason, my webpage isn't displaying SearchResult, while SearchForm renders properly. Thank you so much!

```
function SearchForm( props ) {
  const [ trackNo, setTrackNo ] = useState('');

  function handleSubmit( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // props.onSubmit( trackNo );
    <SearchResult trackingNum={trackNo}/>
    setTrackNo('');
  }
  return (
    <div className="SearchBar">
      <h3>Track a Package</h3>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
        type="text"
        value={trackNo}
        onChange={ event => setTrackNo(event.target.value)}
        placeholder="Enter a Tracking Number"
        required
        />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

function SearchResult( props ){
  return (
    <div className="SearchResult">
      <b>Tracking Number: { props.trackingNum }</b>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared a React element inside `handleSubmit` but aren't using it anywhere, so it does nothing. For similar reasons:

```
function handleSubmit( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    4;
}
```

does not result in the line with the `4` doing anything at all. It's an unused expression. ([Consider a linter.](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions))

Add another state, one that determines whether the `<form>` is being shown, or whether the `<SearchResult>` is being shown, and change that state inside the submit handler.

If all the functionality was inside this component, it'd look like:

```
const [resultsTrackNo, setResultsTrackNo] = useState(-1);
function handleSubmit( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setResultsTrackNo(Number(trackNo));
    setTrackNo('');
}
return resultsTrackNo === -1
  ? (
    <div className="SearchBar">
      ...
    </div>
  )
  : <SearchResult trackingNum={resultsTrackNo}/>;
```

If a track number is a *number*, you might consider changing `<input type="text"` to `<input type="number"` and using `.valueAsNumber` instead of `.value`.

You could also put the state into the parent, and have the parent conditionally render this `SearchForm` depending on whether `resultsTrackNo` is -1 or not (and, if not, render the `SearchResult`)

If it suits your purposes, you could also have the additional state be just a boolean flag, and use just the `trackNo` state. (If you were to go this route, you wouldn't want to reset the state on submit; the `setTrackNo('');` line would be removed.)

Comment: Thank you -- the reason you provided made sense. I created an extra state to conditionally render <SearchResult>, like in the other answer provided above. This solved the problem of searchresult displaying. However, the number inside SearchResult is changing based on the number being input into the form, so if I delete the number in the form, the SearchResult number disappears instantly as well. How can this be remedied so that the SearchResult stays?

Comment: This also means that since the form is cleared when submitted, SearchResult's text "Tracking Number:" displays but the {trackingNumber} portion is empty -- since the form is cleared.

Comment: If you want to preserve the state, then - just don't clear the state. Don't do `setTrackNo('')` if you want it to stick around for some other purpose. And, like the code in my answer shows, you can also use `resultsTrackNo` - the extra state - instead of the original state that you wanted to reset to the empty string for some reason.